# Calculating age in sub query returns null

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

Having this query to count number of participants in a meeting:

```
SELECT
a.`ID`, a.`Start`, 
`Attendance`.`Ant` `Participants` 
FROM `school_group_occasion` a 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(`Id`) `Ant`, `OccId`, `user_birthdate` 
  FROM `school_user_attendance` 
  INNER JOIN `school_user` 
  ON `UserId` = `user_id` 
  WHERE `Type` = 1 

  GROUP BY `OccId` 
) `Attendance` 
ON `Attendance`.`OccId` = a.`ID` 
AND (DATE_FORMAT(a.`Start`, '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`Attendance`.`user_birthdate`, '%Y')) BETWEEN 7 AND 25
```

For some reason, most of the occasions return NULL participants, even though I know there are matches:

```
+------+---------------------+--------------+
| ID   | Start               | Participants |
+------+---------------------+--------------+
| 1384 | 2016-08-28 17:30:00 |         NULL |
| 1385 | 2016-09-04 17:30:00 |         NULL |
| 1386 | 2016-09-11 17:30:00 |         NULL |
| 1387 | 2016-09-18 17:30:00 |         NULL |
| 1388 | 2016-09-25 17:30:00 |         NULL |
| 1389 | 2016-10-02 17:30:00 |         NULL |
| 1390 | 2016-10-09 17:30:00 |           21 |
| 1391 | 2016-10-16 17:30:00 |           17 |
| 1392 | 2016-10-23 17:30:00 |         NULL |
| 1393 | 2016-10-30 17:30:00 |         NULL |
| 1394 | 2016-11-13 17:30:00 |         NULL |
| 1395 | 2016-11-20 17:30:00 |           18 |
+------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Checking out the occasion with ID 1384 for example: (Setting a date since the real start date isn't included in the below query)

```
SET @TheDate = '2016-08-28 17:30:00';

SELECT 
`Id`, `OccId` `Occasion`, 'Foo' `Firstname`, 'Bar' `Lastname`, `user_birthdate`, (DATE_FORMAT(@TheDate, '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`user_birthdate`, '%Y')) `Age`
FROM `school_user_attendance` 
INNER JOIN `school_user` 
ON `UserId` = `user_id` 
WHERE `Type` = 1 
AND `Leader` = 0 
AND `OccId` = 1384 
AND (DATE_FORMAT(@TheDate, '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`user_birthdate`, '%Y')) BETWEEN 7 AND 25;
```

When listing partipants from a single occassion of the ones returning NULL:

```
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+------+
| Id    | Occasion | Firstname | Lastname  | user_birthdate | Age  |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+------+
| 36830 |     1384 | Foo       | Bar       | 2009-11-02     |    7 |
| 36831 |     1384 | Foo       | Bar       | 2009-11-20     |    7 |
| 36820 |     1384 | Foo       | Bar       | 2009-04-09     |    7 |
| 36827 |     1384 | Foo       | Bar       | 2009-06-18     |    7 |
| 36819 |     1384 | Foo       | Bar       | 2009-12-21     |    7 |
| 36836 |     1384 | Foo       | Bar       | 2008-12-23     |    8 |
| 36835 |     1384 | Foo       | Bar       | 2009-02-07     |    7 |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+------+
```

How do I calclate the age of a user, based on a DOB field, and using a specific date as reference? In my case the age would be "how old a user is during the beginning of the year of the start date/occassion".

Thanks!

## UPDATE

Changed my sub query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(`t1`.`Id`) `Ant`, `t2`.`OccId`, `user_birthdate` 
FROM `school_group_occasion` `t1` 
INNER JOIN `school_user_attendance` `t2` 
ON `t1`.ID = `t2`.`OccId` 
INNER JOIN `school_user` 
ON `t2`.`UserId` = `user_id` 
WHERE `t2`.`Type` = 1 
AND `t2`.`Leader` = 0 
AND (DATE_FORMAT(`t1`.`Start`, '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`user_birthdate`, '%Y')) BETWEEN 7 AND 25 
GROUP BY `t2`.`OccId`
```

I.e. joined the "first" table again just to get the Start date correct. This seems to work, but could someone please help me clarify why the original join doesn't work as expected? Thanks

Comment: It would really help if you could post a schema and sample data, ideally as a SQLFiddle.

Comment: Have you tried the `Attendance`-subquery seperately to see what it looks like? Do it, and you will see why it doesn't work. If you `GROUP BY OccId`, you will get one row per `OccId`. The column `user_birthdate` will then have a value from a random row that has that `OccId`. And if you ask yourself now why you can use that column `user_birthdate` at all if it just contains random data, you are right. You should not be able to use it. And MySQL 5.7+ will actually not let you `select` it anymore if it's not in the `group by`, but will tell you that there is an error (unless you set an option).

Comment: Sorry late reply. Don't know if you saw my updated post, but added another join and it seems I'm getting the ages correct now. Need that extra join in order to get the value from the `Start` column.